# RSS feed items only show the content of the most recent item though titles and excerpts are normal

Tags: caching, rss, blogs, feedburner

Can't figure this one out, wondering if it's a caching issue.

My RSS feed looks normal enough except for the  section.

For that section, on every item, the content section contains the content from the most recent post.

Edit: Resolved the issue. Caching!!!!

Comment: I hope it is not contagious

Comment: Please share the URL of that feed...